# Use reduce Subject without calling complete

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm new to RxJS. I'm using RxJs 5.5.2

To keep it simple I want to return the reduced value every time I called next on a subject. Here is a sample code:

```
const sub = new Subject<number>();
const obsesvable = sub.pipe(
  reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b;
  }, 0)
);

obsesvable.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

sub.next(2);
sub.next(3);
// if I don't call this nothing happens
sub.complete();
```

Now if I don't call `sub.complete()` nothing happens.

If I call `sub.complete()` I can't send values any more with `sub.next()`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the [marble diagram](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-reduce) of `reduce` method.

[image]

It'll only emit when the stream is ended, that's why you don't have anything until you call `complete`.

If you want to "reduce" and get the values over time you should rather use [scan](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-scan):
[image]

So your code should rather be:

```
const sub = new Subject<number>();
const obsesvable = sub.pipe(
  scan((a, b) => {
    return a + b;
  }, 0)
);

obsesvable.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

sub.next(2);
// output: 2
sub.next(3);
// output: 5
```